# Copy and Paste Hyperlink change path to absolute

Tags: hyperlink, ms-word, ms-office, copy-paste, word-2010

I just want to copy the Hyperlink from one Word document to another, but after copy/paste Word change address from relative to absolute.

Explanation: In document_1.docx hyperlink is with this parameters:
Text to display: This is link to the document Staff
Address: files/staff.pdf

After c/p in second document (or on the same) I get this parameters:
Text to display: This is link to the document Staff
Address: D:\Documents\Work Papers\Staff.pdf

How to paste exactly the same content???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a Workaround!

Select a whole hyperlink, press shift + F2 (Copy text), place cursor on the place where you want to paste link and press ENTER (don't use paste function).

And you have the same address in hyperlink :)